# ngIf ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if, angular-changedetection

I'm trying to hide the login item from the navbar menu in my Angular 6 app. I have an `AuthService` like below:

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  private url: string;
  private loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  isLoggedIn$ = this.loggedIn.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private jwtHelper: JwtHelperService, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    this.url = baseUrl + 'api/auth';
    this.loggedIn.next(this.isLoggedIn());
  }

  login(credentials) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.url}/login`, JSON.stringify(credentials), { headers: headers }).pipe(
      map(response => {
        if (response && response.token) {
          localStorage.setItem('token', response.token);
          this.loggedIn.next(true);

          return true;
        }        

        return false;
      })
    );
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    this.loggedIn.next(false);
  }

  isLoggedIn() {
    return !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired();
  }
}
```

Here's what I have in my `NavMenuComponent`:

```
export class NavMenuComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  isExpanded = false;
  isLoggedIn: boolean;
  authSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authSubscription = this.authService.isLoggedIn$
      .subscribe(loggedIn => this.isLoggedIn = loggedIn);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.authSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  onLogout() {
    this.authService.logout();
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }

  collapse() {
    this.isExpanded = false;
  }

  toggle() {
    this.isExpanded = !this.isExpanded;
  }
}
```

And, here's the html:

```
<li *ngIf="!isLoggedIn" class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
  <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/login']">Login</a>
</li>
```

But, when I run this, I get the following error:

> Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has
>   changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: true'. Current
>   value: 'ngIf: false'.

I did read about this error, but I didn't understand how I can resolve it. Any help?

Comment: Unfortunately, html didn't make it to the post, please update it.

Comment: @AlexanderLeonov  Sorry! Updated.

Comment: This error will only appear in your dev environment. If you enable prod mode which you will when you deploy the code, it will go away. On a side note, if you use async pipe directly, you won't have to manage states like isLoggedIn and angular will take care of unsunscribing as well. So you won't need to do this.authSubscription.unsubscribe(); as well

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that it has to do with the way you set the initial value for `loggedIn` in your service constructor: `this.loggedIn.next(this.isLoggedIn());`

Try to only declare the variable in your class, and only make it a `new BehaviourSubject()` in your contructor.

Something like:

```
 private url: string;
  private loggedIn: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;
  isLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private jwtHelper: JwtHelperService, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    this.url = baseUrl + 'api/auth';
    this.loggedIn = new BehaviourSubject<boolean>(this.isLoggedIn());
    this.isLoggedIn$ = this.loggedIn.asObservable()
  }
```

Let me know if that changes anything

Comment: No. that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You try to use a method instead of a property to return a observable on AuthService

```
isLoggedIn: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);

isLoggedIn$() {
    return this.isLoggedIn.asObservable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may resolve this error with setTimeout.

```
  export class NavMenuComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  isExpanded = false;
  isLoggedIn: boolean;
  authSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
   setTimeout(() => {
    this.authSubscription = this.authService.isLoggedIn$
      .subscribe(loggedIn => this.isLoggedIn = loggedIn);
   });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.authSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  onLogout() {
    this.authService.logout();
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }

  collapse() {
    this.isExpanded = false;
  }

  toggle() {
    this.isExpanded = !this.isExpanded;
  }
}
```

Comment: @ataravati is it possible to create this issue in stackblitz?